# How can I change rules of rounding numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, tofixed

The results of using toFixed(2) method in JavaScript is following:

```
3,123 = 3,12
3,124 = 3,12
3,125 = 3,13
3,126 = 3,13
```

That's of course correct, but I want to change the rule of rounding (increasing) number when 5 number occures after comma. So I want the following result:

```
3,123 = 3,12
3,124 = 3,12
**3,125 = 3,12** (don't increase the number)
3,126 = 3,13
```

How can I achieve this in JavaScript?

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: NB: rounding of numbers should almost always be considered a _presentation_ issue, i.e when converting the final result of a calculation to a string for display.   Intermediate calculations shouldn't be rounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function customRoundUp(numbers) {
  // Stringify the numbers so we can work on the strings
  const stringified = numbers.map(x => x.toString());

  return stringified.map((x) => {
    // Look if we match your special case of 5
    // If we don't, use the regular toFixed()
    if (x[x.length - 1] !== '5') {
      return parseFloat(x).toFixed(2);
    }

    // If we do, remove the 5 from the equation and round it up
    // So it will round it up low instead of high
    return parseFloat(x.substring(0, x.length - 1)).toFixed(2);
  });
}

const numbers = [
  3.123,
  3.124,
  3.125,
  3.126,
];

console.log(customRoundUp(numbers));
```

---

The refactored version

```js
function customRoundUp(numbers) {
  return numbers.map((x) => {
    const str = String(x);
    
    if (str[str.length - 1] !== '5') return x.toFixed(2);
    
    return parseFloat(str.substring(0, str.length - 1)).toFixed(2);
  });
}

console.log(customRoundUp([
  3.123,
  3.124,
  3.125,
  3.126,
]));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just use basic maths and parsing for this:

```
parseInt(number * 100, 10) / 100; //10 param is optional
```

For each precision add one decimal step.

Answer (score -1):

For those people who don't like parseInt:

```
function customRound(number, numDecimal)
{
    var x = number - 1/Math.pow(10, numDecimal + 1);
    return x.toFixed(numDecimal);
}
```

The idea is, to reduce 0.001 from the number you want to round (in the case of toFixed(2))

But I wrote the function for more generic use, so it seems to look complicate.
If you only want to use for .toFixed(2), then the customRound can be written like:

```
function customRound(number)
{
    var x = number - 0.001;
    return x.toFixed(2);
}
```